# HTTPS with Docker?

Tags: debian, ssl, docker, https, container

I run a Docker container that contains a lightweight Debian and an app on a Ubuntu remote-server.

Right now I can reach the app online over *http://remote-server-ip:port*, but I'd like to make it available on HTTPS.

I wonder which part I have to configure in order to serve the app over HTTPS. Do I have to setup HTTPS just for the Ubuntu remote-server or do I also need to adjust the Debian running inside the container?

Answer (score 4):

HTTPS can't be just enabled in your container, like a setting.
You'll need to configure your web server, generate the certificates and even your application must be able to receive HTTPS requests.

I can suggest you two approaches:

1. The old and dumb style is to generate and sign your own certificates. Then point them in your web server config files. Here is a tutorial using nginx in Ubuntu. [[1]](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-14-04) [[2]](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)
2. The best way is use a Docker container made for this purpose. You can do it by yourself, from scratch, but I'll leave the one I use. It uses [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) and and it's nothing less than awesome. [[4]](https://hub.docker.com/r/jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion/)

Comment: @rotareti, does my answer solves your question?